# How to create PDF through PHP where data is gathered from MySQL and it is in Rich Text Format

Tags: php, mysql, rtf, fpdf

I am extracting Rich Text data from MySQL and want to create a pdf from it. I am able to create a script where I have say only bold, italics, underlined one. It gets a much harder when the data has span tags with text color and background-colors, nesting of lists etc. **Is there a way where pdf can be generated by just giving html page as an input?** As the data contains tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MPDF to create your pdf page feom html

http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

Answer (score 2):

creating PDF using php or any other language doesn't concern with your text format, its upto you will format your text and write on PDF.see [THIS](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/generating-pdf-files-with-php-and-fpdf/6310761)

Answer (score 1):

you could use a third party HTML to PDF api like [PDFCrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com)